# plotting multiple feature on y axis with different y axis scaling

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I have a data set where the columns are time and different features, like this:

```
time rtt  drc rl
1234 2222 23  8000
```

The upper and lower limit for each feature (vcolumn) varies dramatically (huge difference!). I want to plot a single line graph, in which the time variable is on the x-axis and multiple other features are on the y-axis.

I have tried different layers of line plots in ggplot2:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(time)) + geom_line(aes(y = rtt, color = "rtt"))
                           + geom_line(aes(y = drc, color = "drc")) 
                           + geom_line(aes(y = rl,  color = "rl"))
```

I would use `ylim = c(max of rtt, min of rtt)` etc., but I'm not sure if I can add this for each geom_line(). **I want to plot each feature with a different y-axis scaling. Is this possible?**

Please note that in the plot, the red and green lines are not visible (that is why I want to scale each differently on the y-axis).

Comment: Options: (1) Rescale all your data to be on the same scale, (2) Use faceting to place each time series on it's own panel and probably use `scales = "free_y"`. But putting multiple series with radically different y scales on the same plot is generally a pretty bad idea, and so ggplot will by default resist making it easy.

Answer (score 0):

As joran said, you could normalise your values, here's an example (untested)

```
m <- plyr::ddply(reshape2::melt(my_data, id = "time"), 
                 "variable", mutate, value = value / max(value))

ggplot(m, aes(time, value, colour=variable)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but scaling multiple feature to same scare is overlapping and not good in visual with my dataset. I was trying to plot like [link](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tj7H_ORDJ7o/TcgRncP-nMI/AAAAAAAAADM/5Jv3tGu2rts/s1600/fig.jpg) in ggplot2.