# Multiple scale selection in same Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi, plotly

I am trying to use a large dataset for visualization and my data is in long format. I would like to plot a variable Y1 on Y axis, and legend shall be different color based on another variable attribute.

Data looks like below:

[image]

Now, since Y1 values are quiet differing for each attribute, we can not clearly visualize the trends due to same scale. I do not want dual Y axix chart (primary and secondary axis).

I have searched here and some other links, but not successful in getting the right path.

[plotting multiple feature on y axis with different y axis scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081954/plotting-multiple-feature-on-y-axis-with-different-y-axis-scaling)

Target is to get multiple scale on same Y axis, as depicted here, closer to my expectations:

[image]

I am working in Power Bi and can create visual with R as well. Please suggest suitable tools/path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches in R, one using `ggplot2` and another with base graphics:

First make a toy dataset with three attributes on different scales:

```
df <- expand.grid(attribute=c("A","B","C"),x=1:1000)
df$y = runif(3000) * 10^(df$attribute=="A") * 10^(df$attribute=="C")

head(df)

  attribute x           y
1         A 1   1.5744261
2         B 1   0.1675056
3         C 1 976.0232542
4         A 2   4.1204111
5         B 2   0.4594168
6         C 2 449.7775410
```

With `ggplot` use `facet_grid`, and use the strip labels as axis labels:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  aes(x=x,y=y, col=attribute) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(rows=vars(attribute),scale="free",switch = "y") + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(y=NULL)
```

[image]

In base `R`, find the unique values of `attribute` then loop through them, only plotting the axes you need for each graph.  Use `par` to get the individual margins and the outer margin right:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1),mar=c(1,5,0,5),oma=c(6,0,6,0))
a=unique(df$attribute)
for(i in seq_along(a)){
  with(df[df$attribute==a[i],], plot(x,y,type="l",col=i,ylab=a[i],axes=FALSE))
  axis(side = 2,las=1)
}
axis(side = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I tested ggplot2 way, it works well, I used plotly and can see it interactive. I think I can not use plotly directly in Power BI, so try to make it working with some interactivity. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks for so quick response.

Comment: I don't know anything about interactive graphics.  That would be a separate question.

Comment: You showed the possibility and its working well and serving the purpose. I accepted as solution.

Comment: Plotlyjs is interactive in PowerBI. There is also Deneb which is interactive.